# Why does angular momentum point up for a counterclockwise rotation? Why not down?

Tags: magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, vectors, linear-algebra

I am a high school student, and lately, I am founding things a bit perplexing on some topics concerning cross product in physics. In angular momentum, we learned that the direction of an object rotating clockwise would go down (we can use a helicopter as an example). Then, in a magnetic field, we were introduced to a moving charge in a magnetic field and experiencing a force in the direction perpendicular to the plane formed by the velocity and the magnetic field. In both situations, we implemented the right-hand rule to determine the direction. My question is why not the other way, down if up, and the converse? why does a proton go up when a magnetic field is to the right/east and a charge is moving perpendicular to a magnetic field north/up(in-plane sense)? Why does nature prefer these things? Is there something of symmetry? am I wrong to put such kind of question forward? Is there up and right for nature that it understand?

I know that it is a convention and that it holds true. But how does nature identify right and left, and assign a product with a specific direction?

Comment: "am I wrong to put such kind of question forward?" No! This is an excellent question, and you should persist until you are satisfied.

Comment: @ABS, but forget about the helicopter, that is just the way they are built.

Comment: @abs, french-made helos go clockwise (left-hand rule), everybody else's go counterclockwise (right-hand rule).

Comment: Could you use this information to inform someone not aware of any of our conventions (left right, up down, positive charge negative..) which way is right vs left? I think this will help really show the asymmetries. a good lecture on the topic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQ6o1cDxV7o

Answer (score 1):

This is, in some sense, a matter of definition more than it is a matter of the fundamental nature of things.

For instance, in the case of angular momentum, I could easily define it to be $\textbf{L}=\textbf{p}\times\textbf{x}$, which would simply be the negative of the traditional definition. This is a perfectly fine definition of angular momentum: it is still conserved when the system is rotationally invariant, and could be related to a new definition of torque $\boldsymbol{\tau}=\dot{\textbf{L}}$, and everything would still be perfectly well defined. Positive angles would have to be defined as clockwise, not counterclockwise, and every equation you see when you open your physics textbook would still hold. The minus sign is completely arbitrary, as long as define your quantities in a way that is consistent.

In the case of the magnetic field, the Lorentz force $\textbf{F}=q\,\textbf{v}\times\textbf{B}$ could easily have been defined as $\textbf{F}=q\,\textbf{B}\times\textbf{v}$ if we simply redefined the magnetic field to be negative what we currently think of it as, or if we instead defined an electron to have a negative charge. It's all convention.

Nature doesn't care how you describe it. As long as you're consistent, then changing conventions shouldn't change any prediction.

As for the helicopters, you should note that French helicopters turn the other way.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

There is no explanation why nature behaves as it behaves. We just observe it is right hand and no left hand.

Comment: Actually, right hand rule or left hand rule is an arbitrary decision on the part of those defining things.  Right hand won.

Comment: I do not see into ABS's head but it seems to me that his question is a different one. Kind of: why two particles of matter fall towards each other and not apart (gravity is attractive). This is not question of convention. He is asking, why, *in the current settings of convetnions* the moving charge is moving in that (right-hand) direction and not the other. This is not convention. This is unexplained property of nature. I agree on angular momentum,  whis is not an "observable" but rather an "intermediate" quantity.